# Creation of Brownian noise as random walk

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density

I am trying to create brown noise by integration of white noise (random walk).

I created Gaussian white noise. The histogram shows Gaussian distribution and Welch (and also FFT) shows flat spectrum.

Now I try to integrate it

$x(k+1) = x(k) + q(k)$

where $q$ stands for white noise and $x$ for resulting Brownian noise.

But the resulting spectrum is[image]

According Wikipedia I would expect that there should be straight line in the plot.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are plotting the magnitude. Convert your amplitude scale to dB.

Comment: @Envidia Do you mean frequency scale? If yes, then you are right! It should be log-log, not semilog.

Comment: I'm referring to the vertical scale. Is that in dB? Also, some code would be good to see.

Comment: @Envidia The vertical scale is ok. If I make the horizontal scale also logarithmic, I can get the line (decreasing 1 decade per decade). What is corresponding to 20db per decade as is shown here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_noise#/media/File:Brown_noise_spectrum.svg

Comment: You got it. I stubbornly assumed your scale was correct.

Comment: @Envidia Still you deserve a credit to point me towards solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this question does not remain as unanswered:

Making your horizontal scale into log-scale should give you the decade drop and yield the linear amplitude graph.